# Finding polygon from two arcs using CLI tools or some library

Tags: python, intersection, interpolation

I'm trying to convert from textual representation into a set of arcs and lines.

The 'input' I have is:

`The area is within lines joining two semicircles with a radius of 0.67 NM centred on:
641139N 0214540W and
641244N 0214130W.`

What I need is to be able to output similar to:

`ARC CenterPoint, Radius, Start, End
Line End, Start2
Arc CenterPoint2, Radius, Start2, End2
Line End2, Start`

So, what I am looking for are the Start, End, Start2 and End2 points.

I have no problem writing small python programs etc to do this, but I'm looking for some libraries that can help me with the GIS part.

For clarification, the shape I'm trying to describe can be seen on page 'BIRK AD 2.24.11.1 - 1' in http://aip.samgongustofa.is/media/PDF/AD_2_BIRK.pdf